# Making textView loop a growing and shrinking animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to make a TextView grow and then shrink. This process should be repeated infinitely. How do I achieve that? My scale.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:duration="1400" />

</set>
```

Here's my animation method:

```
public void runAnimation() {
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
    a.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    a.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    a.reset();
    textView.clearAnimation();
    textView.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Now my problem is that the TextView grows, but then immediately reverses to the starting appereance. Why won't it go reverse, shrink and repeat the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void runAnimation() {
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
    a.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    a.setRepeatCount(-1);
    textView.clearAnimation();
    textView.startAnimation(a);
}
```

EDIT

Here is my own code that is working right now :

Call animate like animate(textView)

```
public void animate (View view) {
    mAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.3f,0.5f,0.3f,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.45f);
    mAnimation.setDuration(300);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    mAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    view.setAnimation(mAnimation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still the same issue: The TextView grows and finally pops back to the default size.

Comment: @user2410644 Try using setAnimation instead of startAnimation.

Comment: I have added my currently working code. Check if this works. I have no more ideas if that doesnt work... @user2410644

Answer (score 2):

Try this found on some blog. Works perfect for me.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
       android:fromXScale="0.0"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="0.0"
       android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="2000" />
    </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do so

```
ObjectAnimator scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(textView,
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 2.0f),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 2.0f));
            scaleDown.setDuration(410);

            scaleDown.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            scaleDown.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);

            scaleDown.start();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your animation XML file add:

```
android:repeatCount="infinite"
```

And on your animation activity:

```
textmain.startAnimation(animationMainText);
animationMainText.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```